# Authentication workflow for an Admin Panel performing CRUD operations on 'external' data via API?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, token, access-token

What is 'considered' the standard authentication approach/workflow for an Admin Panel (on its own server with its own 'users' database) performing CRUD operations against data sitting on a different server/database through an API? (The API knows nothing about the Admin Panel users).

**Server 1: Admin Panel**

A user logs into an Admin application (OAuth2, grant_type = password). A token is returned. The token is stored client-side in a cookie. Using the token, the user can interact with the Admin application.

**Server 2: Data API**

After user login, the Admin application authenticates against an external data API to retrieve all the data the user can administer (OAuth2, grant_type = client_credentials). A token is returned.

**... then what?**

Are both tokens be stored in the users cookie where:

- The {admin-panel-token} is used to authenticate the User to the Admin
  Panel
- The {external-data-api-token} is used to authenticate the Admin
  Panel to the External Data API (for each CRUD operation the user
  performs through the Admin Panel)

**The above workflow seems awkward? Two tokens?**

Surely there must be a more simple authentication workflow for what must be common architecture ie. Client (the Admin Panel) interacting with an external API where the API only knows about the Client, not the Client's Users?